# How to run my webapp on cloudbees with play2 + scala?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, cloudbees

I'm trying to launch a webapp with play2 (2.0.2) and scala (2.9.2) on the cloudbees platform. To make my test, I use the default scala webapp (generate by play2) and try to put it on cloudbees.
I follow the tutorial : http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Play+2.0

First thing that I noticed is the version 0.3.2 for the play2-war-plugin can't be found in the cloudbees repo. In fact, instead of searching in

> repository-play-war.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/github/play2war/play2-war-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.2/

(where you can find the right version), sbt search in

> repository-play-war.forge.cloudbees.com/release/com/github/play2war/play2-war-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.3/

So I changed the version to 0.7.3 play-war-plugin and 0.6 play-war-core linked to my play2 version (according to the documentation of play-war-plugin github's documentation).

After that I try `play war` and I get

> [error] Not a valid command: war (similar: start, run)
>
> [error] Not a valid project ID: war
>
> [error] Not a valid configuration: war
>
> [error] Not a valid key: war (similar: watch, run, target)
>
> [error] war
>
> [error]    ^

So I use `play package`, it works and makes app-1.0-Snapshot.war in the target directory. Then I use the cloudbees sdk to run my app

```
bees app:deploy -a myDomain/test -t jboss target/app-1.0-Snapshot.war
bees app:update myDomain/test disableProxyBuffering=true
```

Finally, I access to my app on test.mydomain.cloudbees.net

And here the problem, I have got an error :

> Oops, an error occured
>
> This exception has been logged with id 6bjlb33p7.

So I checked my log file on the cloudbees interface but there is no error message. I can see the requests in the Access tab.

Is there something that I'm missing ? How can I make this app works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we now support native deployment to RUN@cloud. You can follow the instructions at http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework#HDeployingaPlay2application if you would like to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the wiki. A few things have changed with the WAR plugins since its release.

The main things are, update the sbt plugin to 0.7.3 and modify your Build.scala file look more like the below.

```
val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val projectSettings = Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings ++ Seq(
  // Your settings
)

...

val main = PlayProject(
   appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA
).settings(projectSettings: _*)
```

And finally, the command has changed from "play war" to "play package"

You can read the offical howto for this plugin at https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still doesn't work. I followed the official howto and I have the same error message.